# Change certain digits in int column

Tags: sql, digits

I have a table that looks like this:

```
tablename
  Id PRIMARY INT,
  value INT
```

The value columns holds all kind of different values and to clean some things up I need to edit the values so that the last 2 digits are always 0, example:

```
old       new 
17364  -> 17300
4958   -> 4900
12     -> 00
312948 -> 312900
```

Is there any way I can achieve this for all rows with an SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using integer division (by 100) and then multiplying again:

```
update tablename
    set value = floor(value / 100) * 100;
```

As a note:  before executing the update, check that the values are what you want:

```
select t.*, floor(value / 100) * 100 as new_value
from tablename t;
```